# How do I create an object of a specified type through a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Consider the following:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base   
end

class Man < Person
end

class Woman < Person
end


class Society < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :person

    def addPeople
        people.create(:name => "bill")
        people.create(:name => "sue")
    end
end
```

How do I define the type of this person? For instance, I want to create bill as a man, and sue as a woman. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify type of an object by its class

```
class Society < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons

  def add_people 
    self.persons << Man.create name: 'bill'
    self.persons << Woman.create name: 'sue'
  end
end
```